# Uploading the Apk in google playstore getting warnings related location

Tags: android, android-studio

In Application i haven't using the location but while uploading the application in playstore i am getting below warning, recently i implemented In-app updates, as per my knowledge in-app updates not required location permission.
[Screenshot of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVAZt.png)

New Permission Added warning: use that have the APK with version code 20 may need to accept the android.permision.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app
**Tip :** Ensure that the new permissions are necessary, and consider mentioning these permissions in the **What's new in the release** text

Comment: Might be there is a chance of your dependency project is using it internally.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

This permission must be coming from any of your dependencies. to check where it's coming from open your AndroidManifest.xml file and click on the merged manifest tab to see final Manifest version after merging all manifest from dependency. you can even check every dependencies manifest my clicking on the library name on the left-hand side.

Refer to the image 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

as per your screenshot location permission is detected in v21.

message from apk v21-
Check your manifest again and ensure there is not ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or any other location related permission you have mentioned.

do CTRL + SHIFT + S and type location see if you find anything related location.

message from apk v20- because you have increased minSdkVersion to a higher number.

Comment: I am using network related permissions these two only : 1. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 2.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE  allows applications to access information about networks like wifi and cellular networks